# whatsapp search filed not clear

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I am sending a WhatsApp message but if a contact is not found then the code is returning `runtime error 12`.

I updated all the XPaths and still the code is producing the same error, and I can't clear the search field and paste in a new number.

Code:

```vb
'Check, if contact exists. If not, skip to the next record
  
If BOT.IsElementPresent(By.XPath(no_contact_found)) Then
    BOT.FindElementByXPath(searchinputfield).Clear
    wsBOT.Cells(i, BotColumn.wcStatus).Value = "Error: No contact found " & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    GoTo NextIteration
End If
```

---

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Welcome shoaib! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346563/selenium-python-issue-invalid-element-state